# Given an $M\times N$ lattice of points, is there a formula to generate the maximum number of intersections, i.e. if all of the points were connected.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

For example, a $2 \times 2$ square lattice has $1$ intersections, a $2 \times 3$ rectangle has $7$ intersections.

Comment: If three lines meet at one point, does that count as one intersection, or as three intersections?

Comment: One. At least under the way that I had defined the problem in my head.